# Structure of Json in C#

Tags: c#, json

My Goal:
Read JSON from site, get values of certain items and display them, after I successfully 
pull that off I will want to implement taking in a value like true and set it to false.
For starters I need help figuring out how to read and write the variables.  I have read 
lots of tutorials and blogs about how to read in the data and parse it but what isn't 
explained is where is the value stored?

Like I have this http://elsite.com/.json and it has this:

```
{
    dola: "p9", data:{
        house: [{
            dola: "p9", data:{
                owner: "blah",   // string
                price: blah,  // int
                url: "http://www.link.com",  //  url/string
                message: "blahblah",
                checked: false
                }
          },
          {
           dola: "p9", data:{
                owner: "blah", // same as above
```

I have built this to get the data:

```
[DataContract]
class container
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public Data1 dataStart { get; set; }
    [DataContract]
    public class Data1
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "house")]
        public HouseA[] home { get; set; }
        [DataContract]
        public class HouseA
        {
             [DataMember(Name = "data")]
             public Data2 dataSec { get; set; }
             [DataContract]
             public class Data2
             {
                 [DataMember(Name = "owner")]
                 public string own { get; set }
                 [DataMember(Name = "message")]
                 public strinng mess { get; set; }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use

```
var blah = from post in container.dataStart.house.data // obviously not the right way to do it
           select new MessageItem
           {
                User = post.own,
                Meza = post.mess
           }
```

with

```
public class MessageItem
{
    public string User;
    public string Meza;
}
```

So basically it boils down to I am not COMPLETELY understanding the structure of the arrays and objects.
Anyone able to guide me in the right way to do the from.in.select?

Comment: How are you deserializing the json string to the C# objects?  Can't you just put a breakpoint in the code after the deserialization and use the debugger to visualize the created data structure?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at Json.NET http://json.codeplex.com/ which includes LINQ to JSON support

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) (System.Web.Extensions.dll) for this; the following works:

```
JsonResult obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JsonResult>(json);

var qry = from house in obj.data.house
          let post = house.data
          select new MessageItem
          {
              User = post.owner,
              Meza = post.message
          };
```

with:

```
class JsonResult
{
    public string dola { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public class Data
    {
        public List<House> house { get; set; }
    }
    public class House
    {
        public string dola { get; set; }
        public HouseData data { get; set; }
    }
    public class HouseData
    {
        public string owner { get; set; }
        public int price {get;set;}
        public Uri url {get;set;}
        public string message {get;set;}
        public bool @checked {get;set;}
    }
}
```